# jquery $.when.done() is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure if I am using the `$.when` correctly but this is what I am trying to do. I am trying to fire two ajax calls and when they both complete, I need to perform some additional work, however, my `.done` method never fires. My alert box is never hit, however, both of my Ajax requests are being executed.

The alert "DO NOT HIT HERE" gets triggered. I would like to prevent that from happening. I need it to trigger within the `.done` only.

```
function ValidateGeneralTab() {
    var isValid = false;

    $.when(SetGeneralTabIsValid(isValid), PostErrorMessages()).done(function ()
    {
        alert("Im here");
        return isValid;
    });

    alert("DO NOT HIT HERE");
}

function SetGeneralTabIsValid(isValid)
{
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "NewIRA.aspx/SetGeneralTabIsValid",
        data: "{'isValid': '" + isValid + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });

    return request;
}

function PostErrorMessages() {

    var errorsCollection = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ErrorMessagesUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(errorsCollection),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });

    return request;
}
```

Comment: The `alert("DO NOT HIT HERE");` will *always* run because AJAX is *asynchronous*.

Comment: Put some `console.log()` statements in your `error` functions, to make sure everything is *actually* running.

Comment: Try removing the empty `success` and `error` functions from your `$.ajax` options. Also, returning a value inside of your `done()` function won't return from the outer method.

Comment: If you want to prevent the `alert("DO NOT HIT HERE");` from triggering, consider wrapping it inside of an `if (false)` block.

Comment: looks to me like you expect the `return` inside `$.when.done()` to return to outer function....it won't. How are you using `ValidateGeneralTab()`?

Comment: Thanks Rocket, I put an console.log in my error and sure enough, even though I was return a 200 response from the server, there was an error occurring with my syntax. Very weird but that helped resolve the issue!